# Python install issue on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, python, pip

I have been using the standard python that comes with OS X Lion (2.7.2) but I wanted to build a UCS-4 version to handle 4-byte unicode characters better.

I had already installed pip and packages like pytz, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, etc., and these are installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. My `$PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

To build a new version of python on the machine (outside of any project specific virtual environments, that will come later), I followed the instructions on [this article](http://webamused.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/building-64-bit-python-python-org-using-ucs-4-on-mac-os-x-10-6-6-snow-leopard/) and managed to build it in `/usr/local/bin`. The problem is that when I launched a new bash window, I got the following virtualenvwrapper error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

The instructions said to move `/usr/local/bin` to the top of the `/etc/paths` file, and since then I've noticed some strange issues. I installed pip into `/usr/local/bin` and now I have assumed that since I'm working in `/usr/local/bin`, and the newly installed python's site packages is now located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, when I do `pip freeze`, it should be empty as nothing is installed there yet. However, `pip freeze` still reports things installed in the old (OS X) site-packages folder. Here's some info after the build:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I uninstall a python package with pip, it removes it from the old site-packages folder as expected. When I install it again, instead of installing it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, it installs it in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (verified by attempting to install it again and receiving `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
). How is it getting that path for the old site-packages folder? Why won't it install it in the correct location for the python install it's using?

I'm getting several other issues since promoting `/usr/local/bin` but I think if I understand this I'll be able to get somewhere.

Can anyone see what's happening? If you need any more info I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the shebang in `/usr/local/bin/pip` was `#!/usr/bin/python`. So pip was using the wrong python and hence the wrong site-packages folder.

I ended up wiping much of what I did and using pythonbrew to install a fresh python and then starting from scratch with that.